# How to check a font whether exists or not in texlive?

Tags: fonts

I tried to install `R` in my system. I ran `./configure`, that results-

```
..................................
................................
config.status: creating tools/Makefile
config.status: creating src/include/config.h
config.status: src/include/config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing stamp-h commands

R is now configured for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

  Source directory:          .
  Installation directory:    /usr/local

  C compiler:                gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2
  Fortran 77 compiler:       gfortran  -g -O2

  Default C++ compiler:      g++   -g -O2
  C++98 compiler:            g++  -g -O2
  C++11 compiler:            g++ -std=gnu++11 -g -O2
  C++14 compiler:              
  C++17 compiler:              
  Fortran 90/95 compiler:    gfortran -g -O2
  Obj-C compiler:         

  Interfaces supported:      X11
  External libraries:        readline, curl
  Additional capabilities:   PNG, JPEG, NLS
  Options enabled:           shared BLAS, R profiling

  Capabilities skipped:      TIFF, cairo, ICU
  Options not enabled:       memory profiling

  Recommended packages:      yes

configure: WARNING: pcre < 8.32 is deprecated
configure: WARNING: you cannot build info or HTML versions of the R manuals
configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of vignettes and help pages
configure: WARNING: neither inconsolata.sty nor zi4.sty found: PDF vignettes and package manuals will not be rendered optimally
```

Now, I need `iconsolata.sty` and `zi4.sty` for fixing the installation warnings. How to check these fonts are whether exist or not in my texlive 2017 distribution. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts$ ls
afm  cid  cmap  enc  lig  map  misc  ofm  opentype  ovf  ovp  pk  sfd  source  tfm  truetype  type1  vf
```

**Edit**

I checked `tlmgr info iconsolata`

```
tlmgr: cannot find package iconsolata, searching for other matches:

Packages containing `iconsolata' in their title/description:

Packages containing files matching `iconsolata':
```

This means probably `iconsolata` is missing in my distribution. If this true how to install the font?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

The meaning of `tlmgr: cannot find package iconsolata` is that tlmgr doesn't know a package named `iconsolata`, not that `iconsolata` is not installed on your system. This is because you made a typo; you should search for `inconsolata` instead of `iconsolata`. On my end, `tlmgr info inconsolata` yields

```
package:     inconsolata
category:    Package
shortdesc:   A monospaced font, with support files for use with TeX
longdesc:    Inconsolata is a monospaced font designed by Raph Levien. This package contains the font (in both Adobe Type 1 and OpenType formats) in regular and bold weights, with additional glyphs and options to control slashed zero, upright quotes and a shapelier lower-case L, plus metric files for use with TeX, and LaTeX font definition and other relevant files.
installed:   Yes
revision:    42871
sizes:       doc: 645k, run: 1273k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 1.112
cat-date:    2017-01-04 22:39:25 +0100
cat-license: oflapache2lppl1.3
cat-topics:  font font-mono font-type1 font-otf font-t1enc
collection:  collection-fontsextra
```

and according to the R's warning, you will find the `installed` status set to `No`.

If you want to install a package via tlmgr, you can use the [`tlmgr install`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#install-option-...-pkg) command. To answer the question title, the standard way to see if something is installed on your TeX Live is to use the [`kpsewhich`](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Invoking-kpsewhich) command, e.g.,

```
~$ kpsewhich inconsolata.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/inconsolata/inconsolata.sty
```

---

I used the word *package*, but this does not mean a LaTeX package (files with the `.sty` extension). Package here is a TeX Live terminology.

Hereafter, *package[l]* detones a LaTeX package and *package[t]* denotes a TeX Live one. A package[t] is a bundle of files to provide a certain function. A font package[t] such as `inconsolata` typically contains

- font definition file (`*.fd`),
- encoding definition file (`*.enc`),
- TeX font metric file (`*.tfm`),
- font itself (e.g., `*.otf`),
- package[l] (`*.sty`), etc.

So, when you run `tlmgr info inconsolata`, tlmgr looks for the `inconsolata` package[t] instead of `inconsolata.sty`.

Then, what determines whether TeX Live knows a package[t] of a certain name? TeX Live has a database of package[t]s named `texlive.tlpdb`, which is usually located in `TEXMFROOT/tlpkg`. When there is no information on this database, `tlmgr info` claims it cannot find the package[t].

Comment: you are true. But in my case `installed` status in `yes`.

Comment: @alhelal what do `kpsewhich inconsolata.sty` and `kpsewhich zi4.sty` say?

Comment: `$ kpsewhich inconsolata.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/inconsolata/inconsolata.sty
$ kpsewhich zi4.sty
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/inconsolata/zi4.sty`

Comment: @alhelal TeX Live installation then has no problem and you should be able to use them in a LaTeX document. IMHO, this site (or I at least) cannot be of much help for why R issues such a warning...